# Passing Class as a Non-type argument in templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, class-template

In Templates as I studied we can only have integral arguments i.e int, pointer to other data types and also template template parameter.

But here I am able to pass just a simple class also as a template argument. Is this valid or what I am understanding is wrong. Here is the piece of code.

```
template <typename T> 
class A {
  public:
         T t;             
};
class B {
  public:
         float f;      
};
template <template<typename> class X, class H> 
class C {
   public:
          H obj;
          X<int> x;                                
};
int main()
{
    C < A, B > my;
    my.obj.f = 2.3f;
    my.x.t = 5;
    cout << "template class object: " << my.obj.f << endl;
    cout << "class object         : " << my.x.t << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of template parameters:

- Type parameters, for which a *type* has to be provided as an argument (e.g. `int`, `std::string`, etc.). In your example, `H` is a type parameter;
- Non-type parameters, for which a *value* has to be provided as an argument (e.g. `42`). Your example does not contain any of these;
- Template parameters, for which a *class template* (accepting the right number and type of parameters) has to be provided. In your example, `A` is a template parameter.

> In Templates as I studied we can only have integral arguments i.e int, pointer to other data types and also template template parameter.

What you are referring to in the first part of the above sentence applies to the second category of parameters, i.e. non-type parameters, and the last part of the sentence covers template template parameters.

Indeed, a non-type parameter requires values of a specific type, e.g. `int`, `X*` to be passed as arguments when instantiating the template, and there are severe constraints on:

- The types that can be specified;
- The nature of the values that can be specified.

For instance, this is forbidden:

```
template<double D>
struct X { /* ... */ };
```

While this is allowed:

```
template<int* P>
struct X { /* ... */ };
```

But constraints are placed on what can be provided as an argument for `P`:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    X<&x> obj; // ERROR!
}
```

The part your sentence above does not cover is the first category (type parameters), and that is actually the one which is most commonly found. Among other things, type parameters are used to instantiate generic collections of objects, such as:

```
std::vector<my_class> v;
```

Comment: double(or float) is not allowed even in c++11 as a non-type template parameter?

Comment: is there any reason other than being historical?

Comment: @Koushik: While I do not know what are the exact technical reasons why this is not possible, I can imagine template specialization to be one of them: specializing for a certain argument (e.g. `template<> class my_template<3.14> { ... };`) requires determining equality between floating point numbers, and determining equality between floating point numbers is troublesome.

Comment: If I write typename H it works, but if I write typename X then it gives me error. Why? As we can use typename and class both.

Comment: @Gaurav: For template template parameters, the only allowed keyword is `class`. For type parameters, you can use both `class` and `typename` interchangeably